# Add a "add Link" to a Content Editor Web part

Tags: javascript, custom-list, content-editor-web-part, html, hyperlink

I have used a Content Editor web part to display a scroll-down list of links.

The code I use is similar to this:

```
<select id="mySelect" jquery110205452414735412181="1"  jquery110209014758248214869="1" jquery1102046470813132006583="1"> 
 <option value="-">-</option> 
 <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option> 
 <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option> 
</select> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
 </script><script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mySelect").change(function(){ 
     if ($(this).val()!='') { 
         window.location.href=$(this).val(); 
          } 
     }); 
});
</script>
```

How can I implement a little "add" button that allows a user to easily add links to this list? I would not like to use a "link-list" web part.

Comment: You want to add options to the select? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I just want to add a little button perhaps next to the title that allows users to add more links to the list. EDIT: Yes that is what I mean but using a simple interface in the browser

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a simple interface like your propose, but store the links in a custom list.

You can use Client Object Model, which is an API to interact with SharePoint using only JavaScript.

You can see samples in MSDN in this link:

[Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)

Form this article, this is an extract of the example "**Create, update, and delete list items**":

```
function createListItem(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
    oListItem.set_item('Body', 'Hello World!');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```